# add namespace to a xml document in C#

Tags: c#, xml, namespaces, xml-namespaces, xmldocument

I have the following xml

```
<book>
   <chapter>this is a sample text</chapter>
</book>
```

and need to add a namespace to it to be like the one below

```
<ns0:book xmlns:ns0="http://mybookurl/sample">
   <chapter>this is a sample text</chapter>
</ns0:book>
```

I tried Greco suggestions but it does not work. 
[Creating a specific XML document using namespaces in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443250/creating-a-specific-xml-document-using-namespaces-in-c)

would appreciate any help!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by loading the Xml into an XmLDocument then finding each node that you want to add ns0 to and setting that XmlNodes's *Prefix* property to "ns0".

Something like this:

```
XmlDocument myDoc = new XmlDocument();
myDoc.LoadXml("my_file.xml");

foreach (XmlNode eachBook in myDoc.GetElementsByTagName("book")) {
    eachBook.Prefix = "ns0";
}

myDoc.Save("my_changed_file.xml");
```

Comment: what about the namespace 'http://mybookurl/sample' then?
i tried the above but the output is the same as the input.