# How to add xmlnamespace to a xmldocument

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

Im trying to create a xml the should look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<MyTestSet xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Tests>
    <Test>
      <messaure>1</messaure>
      <height>4</height>
    </Test>
    <Test>
      <messaure>4</messaure>
      <height>53</height>
    </Test>
  </Tests>
</MyTestSet>
```

Its not a problem to create the Tests or Test elements, but what is the best way to Create the "MyTestSet" including the namespaces?
Im using c# XMLDocument

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This works for me:

```
XmlDocument.DocumentElement.SetAttribute("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
XmlDocument.DocumentElement.SetAttribute("xmlns:xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
```

If you want to create the entire document you've posted, you might not want to forget the XML declaration:

```
        XmlDeclaration xml_declaration;
        xml_declaration = XmlDocument.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "ISO-8859-1", "yes");

        XmlElement document_element = XmlDocument.DocumentElement;
        XmlDocument.InsertBefore(xml_declaration, document_element);
```

In certain cases you might need it.

Answer (score 2):

This question also shows another way of doing this:
[Creating a specific XML document using namespaces in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443250/creating-a-specific-xml-document-using-namespaces-in-c)

You could alternatively use the XmlNamespaceManager class

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d6730bwt%28VS.80%29.aspx

Finally there is always Linq too, you could use a XDocument and XNamespace

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387075.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
XmlDocument xmlDocSPack = new XmlDocument();
XmlNode xmldocNode = xmlDocSPack.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "", null);
xmlDocSPack.AppendChild(xmldocNode);

XmlElement LiftsMainNode = xmlDocSPack.CreateElement("Lifts");
LiftsMainNode.SetAttribute("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");

xmlDocSPack.AppendChild(LiftsMainNode);
xmlDocSPack.Save("SPack"+DateTime.Now.Year + ".xml");
```

Output :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Lifts xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
```